# How to check whether any particular partition exist or not in HIVE

Tags: shell, hadoop, hive

How to check whether any particular partition exist or not in HIVE:

I have partitions in my hive table as below:

country=india/state=MH
  country=US/state=NY

i want to check whether country = "something and state="something" exist or not in HIVE  or using shell script.Please help

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. desc mytable partition (...)
2. show table extended like mytable partition (...)

Execute from shell using `hive -e '...'`

#### Demo

```
create table mytable (i int) 
partitioned by (year int,month tinyint,day tinyint)
;

insert into mytable partition(year,month,day) values (1,2017,3,29)
;

hive> desc mytable partition (year=2017,month=3,day=29);
OK
i                       int                                         
year                    int                                         
month                   tinyint                                     
day                     tinyint                                     
         
# Partition Information      
# col_name              data_type               comment             
         
year                    int                                         
month                   tinyint                                     
day                     tinyint        

hive> desc mytable partition (year=2017,month=4,day=1);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Partition not found {year=2017, month=4, day=1}


hive> show table extended like mytable partition (year=2017,month=3,day=29);
OK
tableName:mytable
owner:cloudera
location:hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/hive/warehouse/mytable/year=2017/month=3/day=29
inputformat:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat
outputformat:org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat
columns:struct columns { i32 i}
partitioned:true
partitionColumns:struct partition_columns { i32 year, byte month, byte day}
totalNumberFiles:1
totalFileSize:2
maxFileSize:2
minFileSize:2
lastAccessTime:1490770378864
lastUpdateTime:1490770379748

hive> show table extended like mytable partition (year=2017,month=4,day=1);
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10006]: Partition not found {year=2017, month=4, day=1}
```

Comment: Thank you Dudu Mark

Answer (score 3):

```
res=`hive -e "use {db}; show partitions {table} partition(country='india',state='MH')"`

if [ ! -z "$res" ]; then
   do sth if the partition exists
fi
```

You can replicate for other partitions.

Answer (score 0):

```
hive -e "use <db>; show partitions <table>;" egrep --color '<countryName>|<stateName>'
```

ex: `hive -e "use db; show partitions table;" egrep --color 'India|MH'`

this will give you all the matching partitions with results that match either India or MH or both